# In Carcassonne Rivers, does the Abbey Tile stop a road?

Tags: carcassonne

Is the mini city on the right a stopper to the road on the left? All the other mini cities have gravel/dirt in the center rather than a road that appears to run through this one.[image: Abbey tile]

Answer (score 20):

It plays as illustrated: the road is unbroken.

See the scoring example that shows the road is "not ended":

[image: road scoring example]

Comment: Specifically, note the second tile penultimate tile in both cases is this one and is included as part of a contiguous road.

Answer (score 2):

Roads are interrupted by intersections (not bridges, tunnels, or roundabouts) and buildings (cloisters, city walls, and houses) *in them* (not adjacent to them). What you see is pretty much what you get.